# Issues converting TIF to MBTiles

Tags: geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, mbtiles

I'm new to the GIS world and am trying to convert a TIF to MBTiles to be used in a tile server. I'm currently running the following commands to convert the TIF, but the resulting tiles just end up as black boxes like the image below:

```
gdal_translate raster.tiff raster.mbtiles -of MBTILES -co "TILE_FORMAT=PNG"
gdaladdo -r average raster.mbtiles 2 4 8 16
```

[image: Tile]

I'm trying to figure out what the translation issue is, based on the `gdalinfo` for the original TIF, any tips on options to explore to tile this correctly? I've tried a bunch of options to no success?

```
gdalinfo raster.tiff 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: raster.tiff
Size is 471, 575
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (31.665837402343751,-17.589284977565395)
Pixel Size = (0.010000000000000,-0.010000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  31.6658374, -17.5892850) ( 31d39'57.01"E, 17d35'21.43"S)
Lower Left  (  31.6658374, -23.3392850) ( 31d39'57.01"E, 23d20'21.43"S)
Upper Right (  36.3758374, -17.5892850) ( 36d22'33.01"E, 17d35'21.43"S)
Lower Right (  36.3758374, -23.3392850) ( 36d22'33.01"E, 23d20'21.43"S)
Center      (  34.0208374, -20.4642850) ( 34d 1'15.01"E, 20d27'51.43"S)
Band 1 Block=471x4 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=0
```

Comment: You have data that is of Type=Float32. Often such data has most pixel values at the low end of the range. Re-run gdalinfo with `-stats` to show the statistics.

Comment: @user30184 thanks for the input. these are the stats i see, how would this influence how the translation needs to be done?

```
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0.84563549141347
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0.091122046113014
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.23949171286047
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=19.43
```

Comment: You should scale the data if your MBTiles viewer does not have an option to stretch the data for viewing. You can try first to let gdal_translate to scale the data automatically by adding the `-scale` parameter.